# WatchKit: setVisibleMapRect vs. setRegion in WKInterfaceMap

Tags: ios, watchkit

[`WKInterfaceMap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html) defines two methods to set the visible part of the map: [`setVisibleMapRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceMap/setVisibleMapRect:) and [`setRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceMap/setRegion:). Both have very similar description, behave (as far as I can tell) in the same way.

What is the difference between these two methods?

To add to the confusion, the [WatchKit Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) example app uses them both in one of the methods:

```
...
[self.map setVisibleMapRect:MKMapRectMake(newCenterPoint.x, newCenterPoint.y, self.currentSpan.latitudeDelta, self.currentSpan.longitudeDelta)];
[self.map setRegion:region];
...
```

Comment: The only difference is if you prefer to work with pixels or coordinates, the result is the same

Comment: Thanks! If you link a source for that in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's developer library:

mapRect

> The region to be displayed, specified as a map rectangle. The size of
>   the rectangle provides an implicit zoom value for the map. For more
>   information about the MKMapRect type, see MapKit Data Types Reference.

coordinateRegion

> The new region of the map to be displayed. The span value of this
>   parameter provides an implicit zoom value for the map. For more
>   information about the MKCoordinateRegion type, see MapKit Data Types
>   Reference.

So, both have the same result, it only changes to way to specify it.

[Apple developer library iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceMap/setRegion:)